# open a folder in intellij using cmd

Tags: batch-file, intellij-idea, cmd

I have added the autorun string and pointed to hold the value to a bat file (in regedit)
which contains this line

**doskey idea=C:\"Program Files"\JetBrains\"IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.5"\bin\idea64.exe $1**

so when I open a folder using cmd and enter command **idea .**

though the folder opens in the IntelliJ idea, I am getting the error like

Cannot find file 'C:\Users\arjun\Files"\JetBrains\"IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.5"\bin\idea64.exe

I could not find out why this error is being thrown though idea is able to show the folder

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to add the path to the binary folder of your idea to your user env variable PATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quotes are in the wrong place. You should only have one set of quotes surrounding the entire path.

```
doskey idea="C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.5\bin\idea64.exe" $1
```